# Grow picture from recyclerview into new activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have an activity with a `recyclerview` in it which is populated with images.  If an item on the `recyclerview` is pressed I need that image to grow to the full size of the screen and then change the toolbar and be in a new `activity` with its screen a full size image of the clicked item.  I then also need a new toolbar.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: is image inside drawable or coming from server?

Comment: its actually a little more complicated than that.  On the app side it is just an empty view and it is populated by an sdk which calls the image from the server

Comment: @AdamKatz so, can't you call the image from server on the next full screen activity by using that sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check shared transitions, this might be what you want.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

I think this will be helpful to you.

[link](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html#views)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fragment Transition

```
public class DetailsTransition extends TransitionSet {
    public DetailsTransition() {
        setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).
                addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).
                addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform()));
    }
}
```

[image]

https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.9t2bqq23m

https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this.. Its quite simple btw :-)

Add the *android:transitionName="ouranimation"* attribute to the views that you want to animate.. 
for example :

In activity_main.xml :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  ...>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
          android:transitionName="profile"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="160dp" />
      ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In detail_activity.xml :-

```
<LinearLayout
  ...>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
          android:transitionName="profile"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="380dp" />
      ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Now just start the target activity by specifying a bundle of those shared elements and views from the source. NOTE:- This transition only works on api level greater than 21 Lollipop.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyDetailsActivity.class);
   // pass the data through intent if you need...
    intent.putExtra("key", detail);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
        makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, (View)ivProfile, "ouranimation");
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

To reverse this animation back to the MainActivity, just call this `Activity.supportFinishAfterTransition()` method instead of `Activity.finish()`....